# Flask SQLAlchemy throws "NoReferencedTableError" when arranging codes in package structure

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning flask and trying to arrange my codes in the "package structure" according to some online tutorials. I have put together some minimal codes to replicate my problem.
First the tree structure of my codes is

```
.
└── test001
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    └── views.py
```

The source codes for each file:

"**__init__.py**":

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somerandomnumber'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from test001 import views
```

Source for "**models.py**":

```
from test001 import db,app

class User(db.Model):
    id         = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username   = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email      = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password   = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    favoritejob_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('favoritejob.id'), nullable=True)
    favoritejob    = db.relationship("FavoriteJob", backref=db.backref("users"), lazy=True)

class FavoriteJob(db.Model):
    id   = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<FavoriteJob ID={self.id} Name={self.name}>"
```

Source for "**views.py**" (putting all routes together):

```
from test001.models import User, FavoriteJob

# @app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# def register():
#    PLACE HOLDER FOR USER REGISTRATION
```

With the codes above, I then go to python3 shell and to the following:

```
from test001 import db
db.create_all()
```

and I get the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoReferencedTableError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-653042798025> in <module>
----> 1 db.create_all()
...
...
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in column(self)
   2045                     "foreign key to target column '%s'"
   2046                     % (self.parent, tablekey, colname),
-> 2047                     tablekey,
   2048                 )
   2049             elif parenttable.key not in parenttable.metadata:

NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'user.favoritejob_id' could not find table 'favoritejob' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

I did quite a bit searching about this error but couldn't find anything wrong with models.py. Then I removed the following line from views.py, which makes views.py an empty file

```
from test001.models import User, FavoriteJob
```

Then "db.create_all()" starts working.

However I can't leave views.py empty as I will put all the views/url routes in the file and will need to use the User and FavoriteJob classes.

I couldn't figure out why the import line in views.py would cause db.create_all() to fail. I am quite new to flask and sqlalchemy so sorry if there is something obviously wrong with my setup. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy defines the table names from descriptive base models (unless you've defined one yourself). And if a model name is e.g. `CamelCase`, it sets the table name as `camel_case`, not `camelcase`.

In your model definitions, you have a related field on `User` model -- `favoritejob_id`, which is related to `FavoriteJob` model (as per the relationship declaration `favoritejob`). As you don't have any explicit table name for the `FavoriteJob` model, Flask-SQLAlchemy will name it as `favorite_job`. But your related field definition has:

```
db.ForeignKey('favoritejob.id')
```

as the table `favoritejob` does not exist, you're getting the error (as expected).

---

You have a couple of options to handle this:

- The easiest option probably is to rename the related table name:

  ```
  db.ForeignKey('favorite_job.id')
  ```
- Or give the table name for `FavoriteJob` model as `favoritejob`:

  ```
  class FavoriteJob(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'favoritejob'
  ```